# View new resource format with the Data Explorer CKAN

Tags: view, ckan

To custom the applications, I have defined a new format with ckan 'csv + carte'. 
[image: Format 'csv + map']
Actually, it's a CSV file with a view map and a DataExplorer view. So , i want to open this format with the view DataExplorer too, but i have the problem with the dataproxy: **Could not load view: DataProxy returned an error (Data transformation failed. Exception: Resource type not supported 'csv + carte')**
So i don't know exactly how to tell the dataproxy to consider it as a csv format so it can be open with the DataExplorer. 
What i've done is to modify the code under ckan-docker_src\ckan\ckan\public\scripts\application.js; especially this part like that:

```
else if (resourceData.formatNormalized in {'csv': '', 'xls': '', 'tsv':'', 'csv + carte':''}) {
  // set format as this is used by Recline in setting format for DataProxy
  console.log("CSV");
  **// Treat 'csv + carte' format like csv
  if(resourceData.formatNormalized === 'csv + carte')
     resourceData.format='csv'
  else
     resourceData.format = resourceData.formatNormalized;**
  resourceData.backend = 'dataproxy';
  var dataset = new recline.Model.Dataset(resourceData);
  var errorMsg = CKAN.Strings.errorLoadingPreview + ': ' +CKAN.Strings.errorDataProxy;
  dataset.fetch()
    .done(function(dataset){

      dataset.bind('query:fail', function(error) {
        $('#ckanext-datapreview .data-view-container').hide();
        $('#ckanext-datapreview .header').hide();
        $('.preview-header .btn').hide();
      });

      initializeDataExplorer(dataset);
      $('.recline-query-editor .text-query').hide();
    })
    .fail(function(error){
      if (error.message) errorMsg += ' (' + error.message + ')';
      showError(errorMsg);
    });
}
```

But, it doesn't work. Where do i have to modify to take into account this new format? Thank you for your help

Comment: I think the real problem is that the data are not in the datastore. When there is a file to be displayed and not data coming from the datastore database, the DataProxy service gets used. This is a fixed service (http://jsonpdataproxy.appspot.com/) and it is not going to be able to handle this format, unless you override it's autodetection perhaps (https://github.com/okfn/dataproxy#parameters).

Comment: Can you paste a sample of the file format? A better approach might be to see if it is tabular and can be loaded into the datastore by adding it to the list of supported datapusher formats. This circumvents the dataproxy problem as described in my other comment.